# Prolog convert strings to pair list

Tags: string, list, prolog

I'm learning Prolog and I need idea how to convert a list of strings:

```
['f(a,45)', 'f(b,13)', 'f(c,12)']
```

into a list of pairs that looks like this:

```
[[45,'a'],[13,'b'],[12,'c']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a list of *atoms*, not strings. Strings in Prolog are usually *list of character codes*, expressed like

```
["f(a,45)", "f(b,13)", "f(c,12)"]
```

Anyway, apply a conversion to each element with a recursive function:

```
convert([], []).
convert([Atom|Atoms], [Pair|Pairs]) :-
  convert_element(Atom, Pair),
  convert(Atoms, Pairs).
```

Instead of recursion you could use [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)/3 in this way:

```
convert(As, Ps) :- maplist(convert_element, As, Ps).
```

To convert an element, you need a parser. DCGs are convenient:

```
convert_element(Atom, [N, A]) :-
  atom_codes(Atom, Codes),
  phrase(("f(", atomc(Ac), ",", numc(Nc), ")"), Codes, []),
  atom_codes(A, Ac),
  number_codes(N, Nc).

atomc(A) --> ([C], {is_lowerc(C)}, atomc(Cs), {A = [C|Cs]}) ; {A = []}.
numc(N) --> ([C], {is_numc(C)}, numc(Cs), {N = [C|Cs]}) ; {N = []}.

is_lowerc(C) :- C @>= 0'a, C @=< 0'z.
is_numc(C) :- C @>= 0'0, C @=< 0'9.
```

test:

```
?- convert(['f(a,45)', 'f(b,13)', 'f(c,12)'],L).
L = [[45, a], [13, b], [12, c]] .
```

atomc//1 & numc//1 are expressed in a compact way, but are very simple recursive pattern matching procedures, i.e. atomc//1 could be

```
atomc([C|Cs]) --> [C], {is_lowerc(C)}, !, atomc(Cs).
atomc([]) --> [].
```

Comment: One little question can you explain (or give a link to good tutorial about that) how this statemat works?
    atomc(A) --> ([C], {is_lowerc(C)}, atomc(Cs), {A = [C|Cs]}) ; {A = []}.

I'm just not familiar wiht using ; and --> in prolog

Comment: `-->` it's the DCG operator, while `;` it's the usual alternative (disjuntion) operator. DCGs are just a minimal layer on pure Prolog, usually implemented by translation, adding 2 argument to rules to implement `difference lists`. The resulting top down parser it's very expressive, mainly because rules can have as many arguments as needed. That make easy to add semantic to the grammar. I've searched a tutorial, found [this](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/7_2.html). At first glance seems useful...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use this code :

```
convert :-
    L = ["f(a,45)", "f(b,13)", "f(c,12)"],
    maplist(extract_args,L, LA),
    writeln(LA).


extract_args(S, [A1,A2]) :-
    string_to_atom(S, A),
    term_to_atom(T, A),
    T =..[_, A2, A1].
```

If you have atoms, just use term_to_atom/2 in extract_args/2.